# Facebook C# SDK - Issues when redirecting to another page

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an IFrame Facebook applicagtion (asp.net / Facebook C# SDK http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).
Default page works fine. I use the foolowing code to authenticate:

```
IFacebookSettings FbSettings = FacebookSettings.Current;
FacebookApp Fb = new FacebookApp(FbSettings);
CanvasAuthorizer FbAuthorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer(Fb);

if (!FbAuthorizer.IsAuthorized())
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
    Response.End();
}
else
{
    CurrentUser = new FacebookUser((JsonObject)Fb.Api("/me"));
    CurrentUser.AccessToken = Fb.AccessToken;
}
```

this code is in BasePage class OnInit that is derived from System.Web.UI.Page. Other pages are derived from BasePage

On first load (default.aspx) the authentication suceedes (user gets redirected to login page, and then automatically redirected back, like in example provided in SDK).

So, when the homepage (default.aspx) is finally loaded, i press a hyperlink that is on the page. The hyperlink navigates the IFrame to another aspx file in a subfolder that is also derived from BasePage class.

Here is where the problem occurs:
When the second (inner) aspx gets loaded, it gets redirected to logn page too and then back. In some cases (Internet explorer / Safari) i get an infinire redirect to login and back to inner page.

what am i doint wrong?

**EDIT:** I had an invalid `canvasUrl` setting in web.config that was pointing to an invalid URL, this question should be considered closed.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to the latest version of the Facebook C# SDK (5.0.1). This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

change this in your web.config
It allows you to keep session when you redirect page

```
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<pages enableViewState="true" validateRequest="false" />
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
<!--<sessionState cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />-->
```